# mac802.11p or decider8011p error

Tags: omnet++

I work with veins 2.2 and sumo-0.19.0 . there is problem with mac80211p in multichannel mode that the channel never returns to idel state after the first transmission. in this way every vehicle can transmit only 1 packet in every 50 ms of channel duration. how can I solve this problem?

`Car.ned` looks like this:

```
module car {
  parameters:
    string mobilityType; @display("bgb=366,359");
  gates:
    input radioIn;
  submodules:
    mobility: <mobilityType> like IMobility { @display("p=332,315"); } 
    nic: Nic80211p { @display("p=94,239"); }
    applayer: C_TestWaveApplLayer { @display("p=94,169"); }
}
```

The application layer looks like this:

```
class C_TestWaveApplLayer : public TestWaveApplLayer {
  public:
    virtual void finish();
    virtual void handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg);
};

Define_Module(C_TestWaveApplLayer);
void C_TestWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {
  switch (msg->getKind()) {
    case SEND_BEACON_EVT: {
      sendWSM(prepareWSM("beacon", beaconLengthBits, type_CCH, beaconPriority, 0, -1));
      scheduleAt(simTime() + uniform(-0.0005,0.0005)+ par("beaconInterval").doubleValue(), sendBeaconEvt);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share a "minimal working example simulation" that exhibits the problem you describe?

Comment: the .ned file :
......
module car
{ parameters:
 string mobilityType;
 @display("bgb=366,359");
 gates:
 input radioIn;
 submodules:
 mobility: <mobilityType> like IMobility {
@display("p=332,315");
 }
nic: Nic80211p {
@display("p=94,239");
 }
applayer: C_TestWaveApplLayer {
@display("p=94,169");
  } 
....

Comment: The .cc file is as follows:
class C_TestWaveApplLayer : public TestWaveApplLayer
{public:
 virtual void finish();
 virtual void handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg);};
Define_Module(C_TestWaveApplLayer);
void C_TestWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {
switch (msg->getKind()) {
case SEND_BEACON_EVT: {
sendWSM(prepareWSM("beacon", beaconLengthBits, type_CCH, beaconPriority, 0, -1));
scheduleAt(simTime() + uniform(-0.0005,0.0005)+ par("beaconInterval").doubleValue(), sendBeaconEvt);
 break; }….

Comment: @ForoughGoudarzi I tried to add your code to the question, but it seems to be incomplete, because you're only using the CCH channel as far as I can tell.